# Virtual host pointing to wrong site

Tags: apache2, virtualhost

I have two sites on the same server configured using virtual host.
Site 1 has SSL enabled, while site 2 is non-SSL.

Whenever, I change the url of site 2 to HTTP to HTTPs, it will direct me to Site 1.

Is there a way to segregate the two sites?

Comment: What do you think should happen when one queries `https://site2`?

Comment: Perhaps, it should prompt error and disallow user to advance?

Answer (score 0):

I had perhaps the same issue? it was caused by certbot (letsencrypt.org) installing the incorrect ssl config into my virtualhost when it was doing a group update for my sites. I resolved this quickly by asking certbot to update the ssl certs individually but I found this very difficult to diagnose because I had cached data in my browser which caused the issue to persist long after it was resolved.

All testing must be in private browsers with cache clearing.

Good luck.